# Theme options panel in wordpress. Best practices

Tags: wordpress

Most free and premium themes offer a theme options panel. Most of them use a $options array to store the options and after that, they just get the options when needed.

From my point of view, using lots of options may increase the mysql load and the number of queries. Wouldn't it better to serialize the whole $options array and then to retrieve it in the header, having access to all the options with just one query?

I need some advices on which one is better and for some other practices around this issue.

Answer (score 1):

### APIs for the rescue

You should

- use the [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) for theme options ([good tutorial by Chip Bennet here](http://www.chipbennett.net/2011/02/17/incorporating-the-settings-api-in-wordpress-themes/))
- or use the [Theme Modifications API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Modification_API), which basically is a light weight Settings API.

Both are specifically written for exactly this.

### Important notes

Remember to:

- delete all options (ask if the user wants to do this), when deactivating a theme, so you're not cluttering the users DB-Options_Table.
- prefix your options, so they can be found and identified easier.

### Frameworks to speed things up

You also got some option frameworks. The [Option Tree](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/option-tree/) plugin is just an example. Most of the projects are hosted on GitHub btw.

Answer (score 0):

wordpress DOES serialize it's options..

> "You do not need to serialize values. If the value needs to be serialized, then it will be serialized before it is inserted into the database"

source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option